# how i can create a dynamic dictionary in python

Tags: python, django

i want to make a dynamic dictionary.

Comment: post error which you got

Comment: What is happening? Do you get any errors?

Comment: post your settings.py and urls.py also, make sure you have followed the steps in the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/flatpages/#installation)

Answer (score 1):

If your flatpage is an app, You need to add it as Installed app in settings.py at first, then register url to your app in project/urls.py, and register url to view in flatpage/urls.py etc.

project/settings.py:

```
     INSTALLED_APPS = [
         '''
         'flatpage',
     ]
```

project/urls.py:

```
     urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^flatpage/',include('flatpage.urls')),
     ]
```